# Cannot connect to SQL Server running on vctl (VMware Workstation Pro)

Tags: sql-server, windows, containers, vmware

I have VMware Workstation Pro 17.0.1 running on Windows 10 Pro, and I want to use containers (I have already used them for Apache [httpd] and PostgreSQL working normally.). VMware uses vctl, so most commands are the same as those used in docker.

With vctl I want to deploy a SQL Server 2022 Developer version (for the process I have done the equipalabres work with docker).

**Source:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-cmd
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables?view=sql-server-ver16

Before we change the configuration, to have 4 cores and 4 GB of RAM.

***> vctl system config --vm-cpus 4 --vm-mem 4096***

Then you pull the container image from the MS site.

***> vctl pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest***

INFO Pulling from mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

REF STATUS PROGRESS

```
manifest-sha256:f59eae35f672300b68470b6f2fd735cf44982cb1585dd7ff40d7869661899b1d Done 100% (760/760)   
config-sha256:05ce0918105bd05db0d2372a38cfea69bfaa10c0295d65f26c2d07b5696f365d Done 100% (4003/4003) 
layer-sha256:bbfe84ab0c13296c87cbb356a7f958281bc739d0a1304f1ea62634416228e54e Done 100% (29915651/29915651)
layer-sha256:fd849ceae6e5535081b382e20c05d570e21c58a4e57ae8363a20a9c4300ae369 Done 100% (464180087/464180087)
layer-sha256:d40626ee3ec6ff7582fe508c79ec9e22d73ba6574324737c78cf136bec7c49a9 Done 100% (77894720/77894720)
INFO Unpacking mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest...
INFO done
```

And then the container is executed. I have tried to make the connection in several ways.

e.g.
***> vctl run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=reallyStrongPwd123" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -p 1433:1433 --name mssql --hostname mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest***

e.g.
***> vctl run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD="reallyStrongPwd123" -e MSSQL_PID="Developer" -p 1433:1433 --name mssql --hostname mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest***

**-Note:**

- MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD according to the MS doc. its the parameter recommended for the SA password.
- The hosted server its running Windows, so the "" are required.
- I have tried several options as described above, using """

INFO container mssql started and detached from current session

***> vctl ps -a***

NAME IMAGE COMMAND IP PORTS IP PORTS STATUS CREATION TIME

mssql mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest /opt/mssql/bin/permi...   192.168.106.146 1433:1433/tcp running 2023-06-22T14:29:07-06:00

I define the password for the user sa, the port is the 1433 of the internal container as the exposed one, I define the hostname of the container with the name of mssql and I indicate which version, in this case the SQL Server 2022 developer.

I'm having trouble logging in, since I'm trying to log in with the user sa (I've searched several forums but I have not yet seen something that helps me).

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online...
```

- The container is running, the tctl ps indicates that it is running (vctl ps).
- The ports are OK, telnet to the port and it responds when the container its running.
- The IP address is OK, it responds normally (vctl inspect <container_name> | grep IP).
- The firewall has the port exception applied.
- No other SQL Server instance is running on the host machine, the port 1433 its not used on the host machine.
- Antivirus are stopped.

Maybe it must be something with security (at least that's what I've seen on various forums), specifically Ubuntu (OS of the containers) the drawback is that I have not yet come to identify what to do to be able to use SQL Server normally.

**vctl log**

***> vctl exec -t mssql cat /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog***

```
2023-06-22 20:29:42.05 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU5) (KB5026806) - 16.0.4045.3 (X64)
        May 26 2023 12:52:08
        Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) <X64>
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      All rights reserved.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      Server process ID is 432.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.06 Server      Registry startup parameters:
         -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
         -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
         -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      SQL Server detected 4 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      Detected 3149 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      Detected pause instruction latency: 22 cycles.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.08 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.10 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.10 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 524288 bytes for 417087 hashPages.
2023-06-22 20:29:42.67 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2023-06-22 20:29:43.21 Server      Installing Client TLS certificates to the store.
2023-06-22 20:29:43.22 Server      Error searching first file in /var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)
2023-06-22 20:29:43.22 Server      CPU vectorization level(s) detected:  SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE41 SSE42 AVX AVX2 POPCNT BMI1 BMI2
2023-06-22 20:29:43.47 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
2023-06-22 20:29:43.57 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1,
2023-06-22 20:29:43.68 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2023-06-22 20:29:43.69 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:43.74 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:43.84 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.00 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.01 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
2023-06-22 20:29:44.02 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.05 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 2, Node CPUs: 2, Nodes: 1, Log Writer threads per CPU: 1, Log Writer threads per Node: 2
2023-06-22 20:29:44.07 Server      clflushopt is selected for pmem flush operation.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.15 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.18 spid19s     [1]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-06-22 20:29:44.19 spid19s     Starting up database 'master'.
2023-06-22 20:29:44.85 spid19s     The tail of the log for database master is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  1024 bytes at offset 396288 in file /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf will be written.
2023-06-22 20:29:45.61 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized.
```

Connection to the container.
***> vctl exec -it mssql "bash"***

I try to connect to the instance.

e.g.
***root@mssql:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P reallyStrongPwd123***

e.g.
***root@mssql:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "reallyStrongPwd123"***

e.g.
***root@mssql:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'reallyStrongPwd123'***

I got the above error.

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server is not found or cannot be accessed. Check if the instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Using SSMS on the host computer.

Connecting to the Server

Unable to connect to the server.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> A connection to the server has been successfully established, but an error occurred during the pre-login protocol. (Provider: TCP Provider, Error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 64).
> For help, please click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-64-database-engine-error

I would be grateful if you have any recommendations that could help me identify and resolve the problem.

**-Note:**
I have seen in git, in MS sites and here in StackOverflow similar cases, but it has not yet been feasible to solve the problem.

I have tried several options from different sites, but have not been able to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that's everything in the errorlog? If so then your container doesn't finish starting up. It should be loading, upgrading and verifying the state of the system databases (and any pre-configured user databases) and opening sockets for accepting connections.

Comment: _A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections_ is a network error. It's not security. It hasn't managed to reach the SQL Server to login because it can't make a network connection. Either the host is unreachable or the port is not open. Remember there might be a few different firewalls between you and the SQL Server

Comment: The data I have seen are the SQL Server log
> vctl exec -t mssql cat /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
They are the ones I have provided before, there is no additional information (at least in that log).
In the log message it starts master, which would be required to be able to make the connection.

Starting database 'master'.
The software usage metric is disabled.
The log queue for the master database is being rewritten to match ...

In the vctl logs I don't see any messages.

> vctl logs

Comment: The drawback could be related to the network but personally I don't think so, since even from the server it is not feasible to login from the container terminal. This command (sqlcmd) is executed on the server (container), and uses the default data; in this case the localhost (I have also tried with the hostname on the container).

root@mssql:/# hostname
mssql

root@mssql:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P reallyStrongPwd123
root@mssql:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S mssql -U SA -P reallyStrongPwd123

Comment: The container starts, it is running and you can telnet to port 1433 when the container stops the port is no longer responding. At the antivirus and firewall level I am sure the rules are there, but in any case I have tested stopping them and I have the same problem.

I comment about the security, since the SSMS extends a little the information and indicates "A connection to the server has been successfully established, but an error occurred during the pre-login protocol".

Comment: The log I have shared looks normal (to me) and shows the successful start of the SQL Server container. Some important points in the log are:
The version of SQL Server running is Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU5) (KB5026806) - 16.0.4045.3.
The container is running as the user "mssql".
The amount of RAM available in the container has been detected (3149 MB in this case).
4 logical processors are being used.
SQL Server has started and is generating logs in the error file "/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog".

Comment: Additional configurations such as TLS, Query Store and File Initialization have been applied.
Initialization of In-Memory OLTP and Common Language Runtime (CLR) has been completed successfully), Query Store and File Initialization have been applied.

In general, no serious errors are observed in the log that could explain the difficulty in connecting to the SQL server.

Comment: I’m in the exact same place as you. I wanted to compare the performance of Colima vs Docker vs Vctl on my Mac since docker is so slow with the DB tests I’ve done. I’ve had to give up with comparing vctl since it just won’t start up sql server container no matter what I try. If you figure it out, please share. I’ll probably fiddle with it a bit more as well, but it doesn’t get far. I’ve upped container memory to 4GB and 4-CPUs and started this container with 2GB of memory.

Comment: I have done the process using docker on both Linux and Windows and it works normally, but when I try to replicate the process using vctl I have the issues. I'm still not sure if the parameters are being passed wrong and it fails to set the password to sa, or it is a linux security issue (kernel security), or the tls. I don't comment but you can also indicate as a parameter not to use tls... I have not yet seen how to solve the inconvenience. I would like it to work because then you can test the performance vrs docker.